# Hibernate not throwing error while parallel update

Tags: java, hibernate, parallel-processing, locking, commit

I got a method:

```
Session ssn = HibernateSessionManager.getCurrentSession();      
Transaction trn = ssn.beginTransaction();

currentActivity = (Activity) ssn.get(Activity.class, currentActivity.getId());  

   if (currentActivity.getState().equals(ActivityStateEnum.CLOSED_COMPLETED)){
 return;
}

currentActivity.setEndTime(getCurrentDate());
currentActivity.setExecutedBy(person.getLogin());
currentActivity.setServerIP(getServerIP());
currentActivity.setState(ActivityStateEnum.CLOSED_COMPLETED);

ssn.saveOrUpdate(currentActivity);

ssn.flush();
trn.commit();
```

It starts from two different threads, which get the same Activity object at same time, make changes and update it. I'm waiting for a rollback if they are started at the same millisecond, because they cant make their changes simultaneously.

I want only one of them to make this commit, and rollback or return for the other. But they do two commits.

Comment: Why do you say they both commit ? Note that you don't terminate the transaction when currentActivity is CLOSE_COMPLETED.

Comment: I have a try catch brackets around it and waiting for exception, but nothing gets there. I should do either commit or rollback to terminate transaction? Haven't seen any methods suitable for it.

Comment: if tx1 commit before tx2 reach line 3 --> `return` (without closing the tx2 ! and without exception)